# TXs in pendingExtrinsics() not always being picked up and then added in the block

Tags: polkadot, extrinsic, rococo, assets, assethub

When adding many batchAll TXs containing mint() and freeze() assets to AssetHub Rococo chain, there are times when TXs in `rpc -> author -> pendingExtrinsics()` just sit there and don't get collected to be put in the block.

This stops my script because it is synchronously adding transactions after the previous one is Finalized.

- It is not a nonce issue, because nonce issues provide an error when it happens. .
- It is not a block limit issue, because that also provides an error when it happens.

Could it be to do with how many TXs the RPCs allowed from one connection?

Could the RPC perhaps have a tag that only allows a certain amount per period of time?

The pending extrinsic eventually disappears, which is probably because the lifetime has expired.

Then i have to manualy resubmit it for it to be included.

What is the likely problem in this situation?

Comment: Nodes usually have a certain maximum value of transactions allowed in the transaction pool. Configured via `--pool-limit` and defaults to `8192`. But this might not be the problem, I'm just speaking from the top of my head.

Comment: You might want to check the logs of the node. `-ltxpool=trace` should give you more information

Comment: thanks, seems like i should run my own RPC if i want to change the limit and check logs.

Comment: however i am not sure --pool-limit is the issue because i am feeding in 1 TX at a time. I am waiting until the TX is included in block then i am feeding another.

Comment: if i submit a transaction after finalization it works very well, just a little bit slower of course.